# Is PayPal SANDBOX returning production urls for you?

Tags: php, paypal, drupal-7, paypal-sandbox

As of today 2nd Oct 2015, the sandbox PayPal API is now returning a production URL, we have changed nothing since yesterday and have multiple different systems all doing the same thing - tried to lodge issue on PayPal Dev support site but it will not allow to submit, form keeps crashing

So yesterday, using PHP SDK  `$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();`

We get

> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-#####

TODAY WE GET

> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-#######

NOTICE the `sandbox` missing from URL

Anyone else have this issue on `SANDBOX` ?

Comment: This is something you should take up with Paypal support.

Comment: Again I have tried calling PayPal, they say lodge a support ticket which I cannot do because the form keeps failing.

Comment: Well, I also see this happening.

Comment: This is happening on my application too

Comment: Also happening for me

Comment: any news on paypal? did they say anything about this?

Answer (score 2):

We also encountered this bug today, what we did to fix this is just by concatenating `sandbox` on

> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-#######.

so it will be

> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-#######.

NOTE this is just a bandaid fix until paypal resolves this issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, wanted to make sure it wasn't me losing my mind :)